# Cambiar color de un cubo al tocarlo por un rayo unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, color

Buenas tardes, estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que tengo un "rayo" creado con Line Renderer y quiero que cuando el rayo toque un bloque, el bloque cambie de color. Como se muestra en la imagen el rayo sale del bloque rojo, pero quiero que sea el bloque blanco el que cambie. Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy utilizando es el que sale en la segunda imagen, pero eso lo que hace es cambiar el color del cubo con "ojo" y no el cubo blanco[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que  a intentado hacer

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio!, es importante como menciona Esteban, agregues lo que has realizado para que otros desarroladores puedan darte una respuesta acertada de lo que tratas de realizar, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 

conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 

[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que obtengas 

buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que el código anterior lo tienes en el bloque rojo, de ser asi debes modificar la línea dentro del **if** de la siguiente forma:

```
collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
```

de esta forma estas cambiando el color del objeto con el que colisionas, de la otra forma estabas cambiando el objeto en el cual se encuentra el script.